# Should I use function create or Route::view to show blade form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I've been trying to learn Laravel by myself and some features are bugging my mind. I'm  trying to display a simple login form with just inputs and a button, so should I use function create and return a view or just declare Route::view on web.php to show a blade form?

OBS: I noticed that if the blade expect any data, I have to go through a controller, but since this won't use it that would not be a problem.
Keep in mind I'm just trying to learning the best and professional way possible.

This is how I would code on the AuthController:

```php
public function create() {
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

##### VS

And this is how I would declared on web.php:

```php
    Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::view('/login', 'auth.login')->name('login')->middleware('guest');
}
```

Comment: Use a controller function.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... that is what `Route::view` is for, when you just have a simple route that will return a view ... in the background it is actually making a route that points to a controller that returns the view you have defined

Comment: though in your case it doesn't make sense to use `Route::view` since you are using `Route::controller` which means you want the routes you define in that closure to be pointing to methods of the controller

Answer (score 0):

If your route only needs to return a view, you may use the Route::view method.

So that's dependent on

1-what you do.

2- the purpose of the view.

3-complexity of your app.

4- data that you can pass to the view.

5- the best practice that seniors wrote.

you will capture the best practices by practice, build projects and see what professional engineers do

In your case you should use controller to hanle the authentication

see

```
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade
```

Answer (score 0):

As Abdallah said, it depends.

You can start this way, if your controller have no other logic than returning the view, delete the controller and simply return the view in your route file:

```
Route::view('/login', 'auth.login')->name('login')->middleware('guest');
```

If then you need a parameter, but no other logic than passing it into your view, you can use a function:

```
Route::get('/login/{someParameter}', function () {
     return view('auth.login', compact('someParameter');
})->name('login')->middleware('guest');
```

Then you might need some more logic, at this point you may want to create a controller to handle it:

```
Route::get('/login/{someParameter}',  [AuthController::class, 'myMethod'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
```

Then you might need some extra "guest only" pages as register. You may want to do some grouping:

```
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login',  [AuthController::class, 'myMethod'])->name('login');
    Route::get('/register',  [RegisterController::class, 'myMethod'])->name('register');
});
```

Those are only some example of what you can do with routes.
You can refactor your route file as your project grows and try to learn more function of the routing of Laravel that may or may not help you as the time goes.

I would also suggest to follow the naming convention for the routes. Then you won't have to much trouble refactoring the route file if you don't have to change the name.